# Drag/Drop only changing element checked once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

### ORIGINAL QUESTION

I've got a draggable element (for the sake of clarity, let's call it `$("#draggable")`) that triggers a checkbox (`$('#checkable')`). When `$('#draggable')` is dragged to a box (`$('#droppable')`), it checks `$('#checkable')`, and when `$('#draggable')` is dragged out of `$('#droppable')`, it unchecks `$('#checkable')`.

The first time I drag `$("#draggable")` to `$('#droppable')`, it checks `$('#checkable')` perfectly. When I drag `$("#draggable")` out of `$('#droppable')`, it unchecks `$('#checkable')` all fine. But when I redrag `$("#draggable")` to `$('#droppable')`, it does not check `$('#checkable')`.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.draggable').draggable({ revert: "invalid", opacity: 0.7, helper: "clone" });
    $('.droparea').droppable({
        accept: function(el) {
            if(el.hasClass($(this).data('accept'))) {
                return true;
            }
        },
        hoverClass: 'hover',
        drop: function(e,ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if(app.is_empty($this.data('count')) || parseInt($this.data('count')) == 0) {
                ui.draggable.appendTo($this);
                $('#' + ui.draggable.data('rel')).attr('checked','checked');
                console.log('#' + ui.draggable.data('rel'),$('#' + ui.draggable.data('rel')).is(':checked'));
            } else {
                var holder = $('.' + $this.data('accept') + 's');
                var child = $this.children('.' + $this.data('accept'));
                $('#' + child.data('rel')).attr('checked',null);
                child.appendTo(holder);
                ui.draggable.appendTo($this);
                $('#' + ui.draggable.data('rel')).attr('checked','checked');
            }
        }
    });
    $('.holder').droppable({
        accept: function(el) {
            if(el.hasClass($(this).data('accept'))) {
                return true;
            }
        },
        drop: function(e,ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            ui.draggable.appendTo($this);
            $('#' + ui.draggable.data('rel')).attr('checked',null);
            console.log('#' + ui.draggable.data('rel'),$('#' + ui.draggable.data('rel')).is(':checked'));
        }
    });
});
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<div class="drop-holder">
    <div class="droparea addressbooks-drop ui-droppable" data-accept="addressbook">
        <div class="text-placeholder">
            Addressbooks
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder addressbooks ui-droppable" data-accept="addressbook">
        <div class="draggable addressbook btn btn-primary ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-rel="4685f5c2-473f-11e5-ad20-000c29b8330c">
            Another Book (2124)
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-holder">
            Another Book (2124)
            <input type="checkbox" value="4685f5c2-473f-11e5-ad20-000c29b8330c" id="4685f5c2-473f-11e5-ad20-000c29b8330c">
        </div>
        <div class="draggable addressbook btn btn-primary ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-rel="04b506c5-4646-11e5-ad20-000c29b8330c">
            default (4)
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-holder">
            default (4)
            <input type="checkbox" value="04b506c5-4646-11e5-ad20-000c29b8330c" id="04b506c5-4646-11e5-ad20-000c29b8330c"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any reason why `$('#checkable')` isn't being checked the second time I drag `$('#draggable')` to `$('#droppable')`?

### EDIT 1

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sx52j3gj/) as per Alex's request. :)

Comment: can you make a fiddle pls?

Comment: @Alex: Fiddle added! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched `.attr()` with `.prop()` and replaced `null` with `false`, [and it seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/sx52j3gj/2/).

```
.prop('checked',true)
```

Have a look at [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and read when its better to use `.prop()` than `.attr()`.

As it says in the docs:

> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked
>   attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The
>   attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and
>   should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The
>   checked attribute value does not change with the state of the
>   checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the
>   cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is
>   to use the property:
>
> if ( elem.checked )
>   if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )
>   if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )

Comment: I wasnt intending to do so. I AM THE NIGHT! http://cdn.meme.am/images/300x/4484.jpg Thanks bruh :)